# Left function leaving out characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with over a 1,000 numbers in roughly the same format:  aaa-111-2222

Some of the numbers have extra parts at the end: aaa-111-2222(bbbb)

I created a column and updated my table using the left function:

```
UPDATE table_1
SET col_2 = Left(col_1, 12)
```

I want to update the entire table so I didn't include a WHERE function.
The problem is when it updates, it is leaving off two characters.

```
Col_1: aaa-111-2222(bbbb)
```

when the function was ran it returned:

```
Col_2: aaa-111-22
```

Which is short characters.  I thought that there might be some leading spaces I couldn't see, so on the orginal column I:

```
SELECT REPLACE(Col_1, " ","") FROM table_1
```

Then I reran my update  and it was still returning short.  I thought maybe I had extra returns and other white space, so I ran:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(Col_1, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '') FROM table_1
```

Then I deleted Col_2 and remade it again.  The structure was VARCHAR, with a Length of 15 (Which is 3 more than I should have)
After I ran the UPDATE again, it is still short 2 characters.

Any ideas on what I else I can do to fix?

Comment: Just for fun, can you insert a record that is just numbers/letters, no special chars, and see if the problem persists?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rTULiMyDFR4qonDJZhwkpp/1). Check the length of each record in the `col_1` column.

Comment: I was looking through the data and after some closer inspection found that instead of 5,000 rows I was over 16,000.  Somehow my data got duplicated so I deleted the table and uploaded a backup I had. After that, the reset worked.  Thank you for the suggestions

Comment: Did it solve you issue?  If yes please mark it as solved or unsolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up noticing that my table was 3 times bigger than it should have been.  I emptied the table, reloaded it with backup data I had, then did the REPLACE and after that it worked just fine.

Thank you guys for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

May be there are leading spaces in col_1.  The `REPLACE` did not update `col_1` as it only applies the resulting dataset of the `SELECT`.  Try use `TRIM` to eliminate the leading and trailing spaces to see if it makes any difference:

```
UPDATE table_1
SET col_2 =  Left(TRIM(col_1), 12) ;
```

Also try this:

```
UPDATE table_1
SET col_2 = LEFT(TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(col_1,'\r',''),'\n','')), 12);
```

Comment: I tried that and the same problem still persists.  It isn't effecting every row, It looks like about half of them are correct and the other halve are short.